# Extract specific HREF with xpath or css

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

recently I have tackled one unusual element that's not trivial to scrape. Could you suggest please how to retrieve the href please.

I am scraping some Tripadvisor's restaurants with python scrapy and need to retrieve Google Map's link (href attribute) from location and contacts section. Could you suggest how to
The webpage for example ([link](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g187323-d7254454-Reviews-Clubrestaurant_am_Wannsee-Berlin.html))

The code of the element:

```
<a data-encoded-url="S0k3X2h0dHBzOi8vbWFwcy5nb29nbGUuY29tL21hcHM/c2FkZHI9JmRhZGRyPVNjYWJlbGxzdHIuKzEwLTExJTJDKzE0MTA5K0JlcmxpbitHZXJtYW55QDUyLjQyODgxOCwxMy4xODI0MjFfeVBw" class="_2wKz--mA _27M8V6YV" target="_blank" href="**https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&amp;daddr=Scabellstr.+10-11%2C+14109+Berlin+Germany@52.428818,13.182421**"><span class="_2saB_OSe">Scabellstr. 10-11, 14109 Berlin Germany</span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box _2OpUzCuO"></span></a>
```

I have tried the following XPATH, but got None as response every time or couldn't get data on the href attribute as if it doesn't exist.

```
response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, '_2wKz--mA _27M8V6YV')]").getall()
```

The output:

```
['<a data-encoded-url="Z3pLX2h0dHBzOi8vbWFwcy5nb29nbGUuY29tL21hcHM/c2FkZHI9JmRhZGRyPVNjYWJlbGxzdHIuKzEwLTExJTJDKzE0MTA5K0JlcmxpbitHZXJtYW55QDUyLjQyODgxOCwxMy4xODI0MjFfMk1z" class="_2wKz--mA _27M8V6YV" target="_blank"><span class="_2saB_OSe">Scabellstr. 10-11, 14109 Berlin Germany</span><span class="ui_icon external-link-no-box _2OpUzCuO"></span></a>',
```

'Website']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `data-encoded-url` that you already got and decode it using Base64. Example:

```
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode("Z3pLX2h0dHBzOi8vbWFwcy5nb29nbGUuY29tL21hcHM/c2FkZHI9JmRhZGRyPVNjYWJlbGxzdHIuKzEwLTExJTJDKzE0MTA5K0JlcmxpbitHZXJtYW55QDUyLjQyODgxOCwxMy4xODI0MjFfMk1z").decode("utf-8")
'gzK_https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=&daddr=Scabellstr.+10-11%2C+14109+Berlin+Germany@52.428818,13.182421_2Ms'
```

You can then remove the `gzK_` prefix and `_2Ms` suffix and you will have your URL.

Answer (score 0):

You try the specific XPath query to get the href like `"//a[contains(@class, 'foobar')]/@href"` to retrieve a specific attribute of the element.